# Number of Pieces a regular $n$-gon is cut into by its diagonals

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons

In how many pieces a **regular n-gon** is cut into by its **diagonals**?

I need a general formula.

By inspection, I have the solution to some lower values of $n$.

For $n=3,4,5,6$ solutions are $1, 4, 11, 24$ respectively.

Answer (score 2):

This is [OEIS A007678](http://oeis.org/A007678), the second sequence when I plugged in your values.  It goes $1, 4, 11, 24, 50, 80, 154, 220, 375, 444, 781, 952, 1456, 1696, 2500, 2466, 4029, 4500, 6175, 6820, 9086, 9024, 12926, 13988, 17875, 19180, 24129, 21480, 31900, 33856, 41416, 43792, 52921, 52956, 66675, 69996, 82954, 86800, 102050\dots $ An article (referenced in the OEIS entry) on the subject is [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9508209v3.pdf). There doesn't seem to be a simple formula.